# Logical Orr ARM

Tags: arm, logic

I'm new to arm programming and I am trying to understand what the following code does:

```
.macro set_bit reg_addr bit

   ldr r4, =\reg_addr
   ldr r5, [r4]
   orr r5, #(1 << \bit)
   str r5, [r4]
.endm
```

In particular I am confused about the `orr r5,#(1<< \bit)` part, I understand that `orr` stands for *logical orr* but I am not sure what that means in the given context. I think `#(1<<\bit)` is seeing if 1 is greater than the given bit, so that will return a *true* or *false* statement but I am not sure what the `orr` command will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the ORR instruction is used for performing logical OR operation. The instruction is used in the following format in the context of this question- 
ORR {Register} {Constant}

Now, the constant here is (1 <<\bit) which basically means to left shift 1 by the \bit amount. Here bit is a number between 0-31 which decides which bit needs to be set. The ARM instruction set allows the constant to have such shifting operations as well.

Comment: So is orr, taking r5 and #(1<<bit) as input ? if so where is the output stored, can you give an example ie what would happen when  r5 =1 and bit =2

Comment: I checked the ARM implementation of ORR instruction with an immediate and see that a destination register is indeed required - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/CIHBDBJH.html

Anyway, if R5 and 2 is passed with R5 = 1, the final result would have bit 2 of R5 set, so R5 would contain 5 now (0101)